# Want to update attribute of parent iframe from child iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have following code
**index.html**

```
<html>
 <div id="updateMe">Old Data</div> 
 <iframe src="test.html"> </iframe>
</html>
```

**test.html**

```
<html>
  <input type="button" value="UpdateToParent Frame">
</html>
```

I can use jquery and javascript

Comment: What's the problem? Getting a reference to a parent window? Finding `#updateMe`? Changing the content of `#updateMe`? Something else?

Answer (score 1):

This is an area that has many security considerations around it - it is possible to send an event to a parent window via javascript using parent.postMessage

David Walsh has a great example on his blog:

http://davidwalsh.name/window-iframe

Comment: link fixed - http was missing